# How do I hide php features from non-logged in users

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, phpmyadmin

I'm in the process of creating a website and I've come into an issue and I'm finding it quite difficult to find solutions online after searching for some time.

So my website is made using the bootstrap framework and has a number of pages where records can be displayed from the database and then edited or deleted and have new records added to the database. Now I'm obviously not wanting anyone just to come on my website and delete or edit any of my records which is why I have created a log-in and register system which works well.

But the question is how do I hide the add, edit and delete buttons from the user until they log in? Or do I have to create another page just to display the data?

My news page for example is set out with the following files: config.php; index.php; add_news.php; edit_news; delete_news.php; read_more.php. Now I want to hide add_news.php, edit_news.php and delete_news.php from non logged in users. Please help as I really am stuck.

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<?php

// load the configuration file.
include("config.php");
    //load news from the database and then ORDER them by newsid
    //you will notice that newlly added news will appeare first.
    //also you can OREDER by (dtime) instaed of (news id)
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY newsid DESC",$connect);
    //lets make a loop and get all news from the database
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {//begin of loop
           //now print the results:
           echo "<b>Title: ";
           echo $myrow['title'];
           echo "</b><br>On: <i>";
           echo $myrow['dtime'];
           echo "</i><hr align=left width=160>";
           echo $myrow['text1'];
           // Now print the options to (Read ,Edit or Delete the news article)
           echo "<br><a href=\"read_more.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Read More...</a>
           if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
               <div> 
            || <a href=\"edit_news.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Edit</a>
             || <a href=\"delete_news.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Delete</a><br><hr>";
               </div>
         }//end of loop
?>
```

Comment: Just wrap the output (buttons, forms, etc) in an if and check if the user is logged in / has the correct role / has the same ID as teh user who created the record / whatever. On login you probably add some user data to the session, so just check if that's there, and if so: show the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions. You can store logged in users information ( User , Admin etc ) and then manage your views and access control accordingly.

Here is the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Here are some examples from php.net : http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php

Answer (score 0):

you can place a php `if` condition that checks if a user session exists before html elements you want to hide, like this:

```
    <?   if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) { ?>
         <div>your html here </div>
    <?  } ?>
```

the easiest option will be to check once if the user is logged in, and redirect him to a login page if he isn't.

according to the code that was added after edit, your code inside a php scope should be:

```
     if(isset($_SESSION['userid']))
     {
       echo "<div>||
     <a href=\"edit_news.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Edit</a>
     || <a href=\"delete_news.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Delete</a>
     <br><hr>
     </div>";
     }
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this out and it works to an extent. Now the code above works well and hides my add news button but it breaks the entire page when I use it on the edit and delete section. I have now edited my question and included the code for the edit and delete part which is located within a php segment already.

Comment: did you remember to remove the `<? ?>`? as it isn't needed if the condition is already inside a php segment

Comment: Yeah I've updated the code again to show you what I've done but it still won't show the index.php page. Adding that bit of code breaks it. All other pages work though.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but it is still breaking the page. Now what Wilf has done above works but he has included read more but I want that available to all users. I think it might be an issue with echo but I'm not sure.

Comment: added the `echo` without readmore to the original answer, try it

Answer (score 0):

You should use [php sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Before showing the delete/update buttons check if the user has logged in. And that should be stored as a session variable. What is more, you should make an extra layer of protection so that when someone is trying to update something, check if they can.

Anyways I suggest using a framework when you're building a web application. It makes life much easier once you get the hang of it. What is more, most of the frameworks have different packages/plugins/extensions with functionality you can use in your application.

As an authentication system is something that very many applications have, you can just install the authentication and user system.

Answer (score 0):

Find if user is logged in or not . You might have session variable to check if the user is logged in . so , simply check if that session variable is set..
Example..

```
If (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   // show that records
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php

// load the configuration file.
include("config.php");
//load news from the database and then ORDER them by newsid
//you will notice that newlly added news will appeare first.
//also you can OREDER by (dtime) instaed of (news id)
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY newsid DESC",$connect);
//lets make a loop and get all news from the database
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {//begin of loop
       //now print the results:
       echo "<b>Title: ";
       echo $myrow['title'];
       echo "</b><br>On: <i>";
       echo $myrow['dtime'];
       echo "</i><hr align=left width=160>";
       echo $myrow['text1'];
       // Now print the options to (Read ,Edit or Delete the news article)
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
           echo "<br><a href=\"read_more.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Read More...</a>
        || <a href=\"edit_news.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Edit</a>
         || <a href=\"delete_news.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Delete</a><br><hr>";
    }//if session
     }//end of loop
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I noticed you have included read_more.php but I would like to have the user see that and use it even if there not logged in.